# Django Forms: field_order fails to work in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

My `field_order` variable fails to correctly set the order. I'm trying to reorganize the form so that the bottom two fields are at the top of the form, as illustrated  here: [image]

Here is my class from **forms.py**. I set the `field_order` in `class Meta`, but it doesn't re-arrange my form and I don't know why? I do not get any errors when I run my code either.

```
class changeLockForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(changeLockForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['roomLoc'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Models.Room.objects.filter(owner=None) | Models.Room.objects.filter(owner=user), label='Room Location')
        self.fields['lockName'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Models.Lock.objects.filter(owner=None) | Models.Lock.objects.filter(owner=user), label="Current Lock Name")
        
    newNameBool = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Change Name? Y/N',)
    newLockName = forms.CharField(required=False, min_length=2, max_length=20, label='New Lock Name', disabled=True)
    state = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='LOCKED/UNLOCKED')
    code1 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1000, min_value=1000, max_value=9999, label='First Code')
    code2 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1000, min_value=1000, max_value=9999, label='Second Code')
    code3 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1000, min_value=1000, max_value=9999, label='Third Code')
    code4 = forms.IntegerField(initial=1000, min_value=1000, max_value=9999, label='Fourth Code')
    class Meta:
        model = Models.Lock
        fields = ['lockName','newNameBool','newLockName','roomLoc', 'state', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4']
        field_order = ['lockName', 'newNameBool', 'newLockName', 'roomLoc', 'state', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial field ordering occurs when `super()` is called in your `__init__()` method.  When you reassign new values to the `roomLoc` and `lockName` keys in the `self.fields` dict the initial ordering is disrupted.

You can simply ask the form to reorder itself using the [`order_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.order_fields) method at the end of your `__init__()` method:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    self.order_fields(self.Meta.fields)
```

In addition [`field_order`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order) is not a Meta option (so that can be removed from your Meta class - it's not being used by Django there). It can be used as an attribute directly on the `Form` class or as an optional keyword argument passed to the `Form`'s constructor.